# Rails controller processing as HTML instead of SOAP by INVOKE (BPEL) activity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, soap, bpel, wash-out

I've created a simple web service, only concat two strings. I created this web service with the wash_out gem. So my web service is on my rails server.

controller with concat method:

```
class ContextserverController < ApplicationController
  include WashOut::SOAP

  soap_service namespace: 'urn:WashOut', wsdl_style: 'document'

  soap_action "concat",
    :args   => { :concatRequest => {:a => :string, :b => :string }},
    :return => {:result => :string}

  def concat
    # something I want to do in ruby
    puts "*******************************************************************"
    puts "************************   CONCAT   *******************************"
    puts "*******************************************************************"

    puts params
    puts params[:concatRequest][:a]
    puts params[:concatRequest][:b]
    result = params[:concatRequest][:a] + params[:concatRequest][:b]
    puts "ERGEBNIS: " + result
    puts "*******************************************************************"
    # and then send response to BPEL process
    render :soap => ( { :result => result } )
  end
end
```

On the other side I have my BPEL process where I want to INVOKE this web service.
When I want to invoke the process ...

```
[INVOKE] Failure during invoke: Error sending message (mex={PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphraka328skerr [PID {http://localhost:8080/test}TestProcess-5609] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@1f939560.concat(...) Status ASYNC}): SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaratio
[BpelRuntimeContextImpl] ActivityRecovery: Registering activity 15, failure reason: Error sending message (mex={PartnerRoleMex#hqejbhcnphraka328skerr [PID {http://localhost:8080/test}TestProcess-5609] calling org.apache.ode.bpel.epr.WSAEndpoint@1f939560.concat(...) Status ASYNC}): SOAP message MUST NOT contain a Document Type Declaratio on channel 27
```

On the rails server log I see the following:

```
Processing by ContextserverController#concat as HTML
#<ActionDispatch::Http::Headers:0x007fc82a9c56b8>
*******************************************************************
************************   CONCAT   *******************************
*******************************************************************
{}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 12ms
```

I think the problem is the processing as **HTML**.
If I test the web service with eclipse Web Service Explorer the web service will be processed in **SOAP**!

When I test the web service directly with Web Service Explorer:

```
Processing by ContextserverController#concat as SOAP
*******************************************************************
************************   CONCAT   *******************************
*******************************************************************
{"concatRequest"=>{"a"=>"a", "b"=>"b"}}
a
b
ERGEBNIS: ab
*******************************************************************
  Rendered /Users/jordan/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/wash_out-0.9.2/app/views/wash_with_soap/document/response.builder (1.2ms)
```

So I don't understand why the process will executed as HTML when I invoke the process.

Answer (score 0):

Web Service Explorer is likely sending an 'Accept' header containing 'application/soap+xml', which is not done by the BPEL process. You can check request.env for the content of action_dispatch.request.accepts to see which Accept header you are receiving.